# Predicting rare events using machine learning algorithms in R

Tags: machine-learning, rare-events, unbalanced-classes

[image]

I am working on a dataset in which independent variables have 80 % missing values. The dependent variable contains 0 and 1 only (binary class) in which 0.02% are "1" and rest 99.98 % are "0".

The observations of dependent variable and independent variable varies with respect to time and with respect to type of a indicator variable. Since the events are very rare, I am not getting any good result with SVM one- classification, RandomForest and GBM in R.

What should be the best strategy to deal with such kind of dataset in order to predict the minority class accurately ? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include a small snippet of your dataset for understanding it better?

Comment: I have a dataset of around 2 lakh rows with 250 variables. Here is the attached sample data.

Comment: Please edit the question and include it inside there

Comment: Did you even bother trying logistic regression with a tuned threshold?

Comment: @ssdeccontrol : Yes, I tried logistic regression but the model was not converging.